# Laptop's backlight turns on with Integrated GFX, but not Discrete GFX

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, laptop-display, backlight

I have an MSI GT72 from 2014. A few weeks back, the MXM GTX980M died.

Since then, I have been able to use the computer just fine with only the integrated GPU.

Today, we installed a new MXM GTX980M. The monitor works fine in integrated graphics, but MSI has software that allows you to swap between integrated and discrete graphics card, so I switch and reboot.

Switching over the GTX980M, the computer boots and functions, but the backlight for the monitor does not turn on at all. I am able to plug in an external monitor with mirror mode to do any changes. The monitor is properly detected and displays images, and I can see that it is working properly with a flashlight, but it is otherwise unlit.

These are the steps I have attempted to fixing the issue.

- Nvidia drivers uninstalled and reinstalled.
- Increase/decrease brightness through Display Settings
- Increase/decrease brightness from keyboard.
- Disable/enable display through Display Settings.
- Update monitor drivers (up to date).

If I switch back to integrated graphics, the backlight works again, and I am able to consistently replicate this issue.

I have not changed any BIOS or vBIOS as of yet.

Comment: I'd update the BIOS and contact MSI if there is still warranty on the laptop.

Comment: Could you imagine that the card failed exactly 1 day after my 2 year warranty expired? :P Would I be updating the BIOS or the vBIOS?

Comment: @Compass I would start with updating BIOS first; with a new card, you probably won't need a new vBIOS (hopefully).